# View load methods not firing

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm loading a view like this:

```
if(commentSubmissionView == nil){
    commentSubmissionView = [[CommentSubmissionController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CommentSubmissionView" bundle:nil];  
}
[self.view addSubview:commentSubmissionView.view];
```

viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear in commentSubmissionView  do not fire.  Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `viewWillAppear:` isn't completely clear but have a look at what it says:

> This method is called in response to a
>   view being added either directly or
>   indirectly to a window. You add views
>   to a window directly by using the
>   addSubview: method to add them to the
>   window’s view hierarchy. You can also
>   add a view indirectly in several ways,
>   including by pushing it onto a
>   navigation stack or by presenting it
>   modally (using the
>   presentModalViewController:animated:
>   method). This method is called before
>   the view is actually added to the
>   window and before any animations are
>   configured.

The `viewDidAppear:` and `viewWillAppear:` methods will only be called if you are:

1. Adding them to a window (adding to a view does not count -- it must be a window)
2. Using `pushViewController:` or `presentModalViewController:animated:` or switching tabs in a tab controller or any other situation where an Apple-provided view controller adds the view controller and its view for you.

In the situation you have, where you are adding a view to another view, you must invoke `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:` on the view controller yourself or they won't happen.

I don't know why `viewDidLoad` was not getting invoked for you initially. It will always be invoked after `loadView`, when the `view` property accessor is invoked on the controller for the first time, unless an error occurs. It is possible the view load was failing (you'd have to check the console log).

You do not need to follow `addSubview:` with `bringSubviewToFront:` since `addSubview:` always adds to the front. Again, from the documentation of `addSubview:`

> Adds a view to the receiver’s subviews
>   so it’s displayed above its siblings.

Comment: Thanks.  In #1, you say "...adding to a view does not count..."  Yet the documentation states, "You add views to a window directly by using the addSubview: method...".  Since I am using addSubview, the method should fire correct?

Comment: addSubview: only causes viewDidAppear: and viewWillAppear: to fire if you invoke addSubview: on a window (i.e. [window addSubview:newView]). Since you are invoking it on a view (i.e. [view addSubview:newView]), it won't work. I don't know why Apple have made this distinction but they have.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `addSubview:` then you also need to use `bringSubviewToFront:` as follows:

```
if(commentSubmissionView == nil){
    commentSubmissionView = [[CommentSubmissionController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CommentSubmissionView" bundle:nil];  
}
[self.view addSubview:commentSubmissionView.view];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:commentSubmissionView.view];
```

Comment: That will throw this exception:

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[UIView makeKeyAndVisible]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x352550'

Comment: You can also call viewDidLoad and friends explicitly though that brings with it the risk of you forgetting about it and having them called weirdly in the future.

Comment: viewDidLoad does fire now but not viewWillAppear.  Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` are called on UIViewController subclasses, `commentSubmissionView` looks like a UIView subclass. As Matt mentioned, you probably want to push/present a view controller instead of just adding a subview.